# Matrix dependency

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

\begin{bmatrix}
-8 & 6\\ 
 a& -6\\ 
 6& b
\end{bmatrix}

I'm asked to find for which values is this vector linearly dependent, I suppose I should add one column of zeroes and then find the determinant.
I get that the answer is 0; is that correct ?

Comment: Do you mean indipendence of columns of the matrix?You want to find a,b such that the two vectors are indipendent?

Comment: I think you should explain better the problem

Comment: If you have a column of zeroes, the determinant will always be $0$

Answer (score 0):

No, if $a=8$ and $b=-\dfrac92$, then they're linearly dependent.

[I solved $a\times\dfrac6{-8}=-6$ and $6\times\dfrac6{-8}=b$.]

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only two vectors, the dependency is equivalent to be multiple of each other. Now the first row presents the ratio, and then what @J. W. Tanner did. Notice that both $a$ and $b$ must be equal to what found simultaneously. So we have only **ONE** solution.

Comment: ok , thank you im confident i understand